Different interval confidences on the same forest plot (R, survival)
I'm currently working on survival functions and especially on forest plots. I would like to plot the different levels of confidence intervals on the same line, with different colors or shades.
To do so, I use the forest function from the forestploter package. I use this package because it is greatly adaptable. However, I'm not able to have these different CIs. For the moment, I was able to get the different CIs but not on the same line.
Do anyone of you know how I could fix it ?
Here is an example of what I've been doing with the lung data from the survival package.
library(survival)
library(forestploter)

# Fit a Cox proportional hazards regression model
reg <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog + ph.karno, data = lung)

  # Extract variable names, coefficients, and standard errors
variables <- names(coef(reg))
beta <- coef(reg)
se <- sqrt(diag(reg$var))

  # Calculate hazard ratios (HR)
HR <- exp(beta)

  # Calculate p-values
p <- 1 - pchisq((beta / se)^2, 1)

  # Calculate confidence intervals (CI)
CI_95 <- exp(confint(reg))
CI_90 <- exp(confint(reg, level = 0.90))

  # Format CI string for HR table
CI_hr_95 <- sprintf("%.2f (%.2f to %.2f)", HR, CI_95[, 1], CI_95[, 2])

# Create essai data.table with results
essai <- data.table(
  variables,  # Variable names
  beta,        # Coefficients
  p = round(p, 3),  # Rounded p-values
  HR,          # Hazard ratios
  CI_95_lower = CI_95[, 1],  # Lower CI for 95%
  CI_95_upper = CI_95[, 2],  # Upper CI for 95%
  CI_90_lower = CI_90[, 1],  # Lower CI for 90%
  CI_90_upper = CI_90[, 2],  # Upper CI for 90%
  CI_hr_95     # Formatted HR CI string
)

essai$` `<- paste(rep(" ", 50), collapse = " ")

# Define forest plot theme
tm <- forest_theme(
  base_size = 12,      # Font size
  base_family = "",    # Font family (optional)
  ci_pch = 10,         # Point character for CI lines
  ci_col = "black",    # Color for CI lines
  ci_alpha = 1,        # Transparency of CI lines
  ci_fill = NULL,      # Fill color for CI regions (optional)
  ci_lty = 1,          # Line type for CI lines
  ci_lwd = 2,          # Line width for CI lines
  ci_Theight = NULL,    # Height for CI tick marks (optional)
  legend_name = "CI threshold",  # Legend label for CI lines
  legend_value = c("90%", "95%")  # Legend values for CI lines
)

# Prepare data for forest plot
forest_data <- essai[, c(1, 9, 10, 3)]  # Select relevant columns

# Define forest plot elements
forest <- forest(
  forest_data,
  est = list(essai$HR, essai$HR),           # Estimate values (HR for both lines)
  lower = list(essai$CI_90_lower, essai$CI_95_lower),  # Lower CI for each line
  upper = list(essai$CI_90_upper, essai$CI_95_upper),  # Upper CI for each line
  sizes = 0.5,                               # Point size
  ci_column = 3,                             # Column with CI information
  ref_line = 1,                               # Reference line at HR=1
  ticks_at = c(0, 1, 5.3),                     # X-axis ticks
  xlim = c(0, 5.3),                           # X-axis limits
  nudge_y = 0.3,                              # Vertical nudge for labels
# Even with nudge_y = 0, it is not on the same line
  theme = tm,                                # Forest plot theme
  arrow_lab = c("Longer WT", "Shorter WT")    # Labels for HR lines (optional)
)

# Create the forest plot
plot(forest)

PS : For who might know this handbook, I would like to recreate the Figure 19.10 (p 468) from Regression Modeling Strategies: With Applications to Linear Models, Logistic Regression, and Survival Analysis (2015)

PS 2 : With my real data, using the forest function is great, because it makes easier to deal with label and to plot HR and CIs for interaction variables.
Thanks.

Wouldn't the CIs overlap? Can you provide a snapshot of Figure 19.10?

Hey @Edward, I've edited my question with the picture. I was not sure it was ok to add a graph. As you can see, the darker, the smaller the CI is. It's basically what I would like to do. And indeed, the CIs overlap.
